# javascript regex to add line break after period

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to use a regex in javascript to add a line break after every sentence to json data that is being formatted as an html variable.

Locating it based just on the period wasnt working -- there seemed to be extra characters in the json data or something else that was causing line breaks every 3 or 4 words.

So Im trying to search for a period with the look-ahead for a capital letter. But this is adding the line break before every capital letter, not just ones that follow a period.

Im pretty new to regular expressions so any help would be very very helpful!

Right now the search parameter for the period followed by a capital letter is: `/.(?=[A-Z])/g`

The javascript is: `description.replace(/.(?=[A-Z])/g, '<br /><br />');`

Comment: Here, have a regex tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues. 
First `.` in RegExp means, "any character". 
Second, I don't think you need the `?=`. I think you're probably looking for something like this:

```
 /\.(\s+)[A-Z]/g
```

Comment: Oh yes, thank you -- that definitely explains it... That is finding it correctly but now Im replacing the period and capital letter with the line break. Do you know what the replace parameter should be so that it includes the matched items -- so the replace term would be period + line break + capital letter? I tried \1.

Comment: Thanks for the help all -- this got it:

description.replace(/(\.(\s+))/g, '\$1 <br /><br />');

Comment: You don't need the parens around (\s+) in the example above, just (\.\s+), plus you don't need a space between \$1 and <br />.  That makes the final replace call:   description.replace(/(\.\s+)/g,"\$1<br /><br />");

Answer (score 0):

A period `.` is a wildcard that matches any single character. To match an actual period you must escape it in the regex `\.` so your line

`description.replace(/.(?=[A-Z])/g, '<br /><br />');`

becomes

`description.replace(/\.(?=[A-Z])/g, '<br /><br />');`

I haven't done any testing on this to check the rest of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your `.` like this `.' so it doesn't match any character.

```
description.replace(/\.(?=[A-Z])/g, '<br /><br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

For more complex sentence structures, including quotes, parenthesis, etc. this is the solution I came up with ([gist](https://gist.github.com/Daniel-Hug/0082b179797cfc6c71780b7c79d4048e)):

1. Regular expression:

   ```
   ([^\dA-Z][\.!?][\)\]'"”’]* +)
   ```
2. Replace string:

   ```
   $1\n
   ```